# How can I fix <video> from beeing freezing and getting slow?

Tags: javascript, video, playlist

I have a website that have many videos. the videos are playing as playlist. The problem is after a while or when I change the tabs and get back to it, it become freezing and slow.
Here is my codes!

```js
const colus = document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-3");

const videosone = colus[0].getElementsByTagName('video');

videosone[0].play();

let i = 0;
let j = 0;

myHandlerone(0);

function myHandlerone(i) {

videosone[i].addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e){

if (this.currentTime > 14) {

this.pause();
this.currentTime= 0;

}})

videosone[i].addEventListener('pause',function(e){

if (i < videosone.length - 1) {

j = i + 1;

videosone[j].style.display = "block";
videosone[i].style.display = "none";
videosone[j].play()

i = i + 1;
myHandlerone(i);

} else {

videosone[0].style.display = "block";
videosone[i].style.display = "none";
videosone[0].play()

myHandlerone(0);

}})}


const videostwo = colus[1].getElementsByTagName('video');

videostwo[0].play();

let k = 0;
let l = 0;

myHandlertwo(0);

function myHandlertwo(k) {

videostwo[k].addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e){

if (this.currentTime > 14) {

this.pause();
this.currentTime= 0;

}})

videostwo[k].addEventListener('pause',function(e){

if (k < videostwo.length - 1) {

l = k + 1;

videostwo[l].style.display = "block";
videostwo[k].style.display = "none";
videostwo[l].play()

k = k + 1;
myHandlertwo(k);

} else {

videostwo[0].style.display = "block";
videostwo[k].style.display = "none";
videostwo[0].play()

myHandlertwo(0);

}})}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div id="myvideo" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
      <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/hren1brbm_1080__D.mp4"></video>
      <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/kpll3r_1080__D.mp4"></video>
      <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/artist-drawing-henna-tattoo-on-woman-hand-in-india_rovjoopfdg_1080__D.mp4"></video>
      <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/bjfexlpu__d_1080__D.mp4"></video>
      
      <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/videoblocks-gamer-boy-playing-video-games-on-smartphone_bceuskkvv_1080__D.mp4"></video>
      <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/videoblocks-worker-at-factory-welding_bue3j8esmx_1080__D.mp4"></video>
      <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/videoblocks-young-grace-woman-practicing-elements-with-aerial-hoop_rneekqvj3f_1080__D.mp4"></video>
      <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/s0xvso2l4v_1080__D.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div id="myvideo" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
      

         
          
          <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/videoblocks-celebrants-dancing-during-the-color-holi-festival_hfbynffi_1080__D.mp4"></video>
          <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/rs_s4wcvnemng_1080__D.mp4"></video>
          
          <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/slow-motion-tennis-ball.mp4"></video>
          <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/snake-charmer-in-india.mp4"></video>
          <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/ac0w7f_x_1080__D+(1).mp4"></video>
      <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/ah4rz_1080__D.mp4"></video>
       <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/ah4rz_1080__D.mp4"></video>
       <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/hj.mp4"></video>
       <video muted="muted" style="display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" src="https://viddy.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/hot-summer-day.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="center-table">

  <p><span class="about">About Us</span><br><br><span class="subtitle">Viddy is a global social network for mobile video.<br>
Creators entertain the world with their talents.</span><br><br>

<span class="sub">Viddy has team members around the world in Detroit, Los Angeles, San Francisco, Las Vegas, Chicago, New York, Miami, London, Paris, Dubai, Tokyo, Barcelona, Zimbabwe, Kyiv, Singapore, Seoul, Prague, Mumbai, and Moscow. </span>

</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div><br>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.sub{font-family: "Product Sans";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #4f535a;
    text-decoration: justify !important;}
.subtitle{
    font-family: "Product Sans Bold";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #161823;
    text-align: justify !important;
}
.about{
    font-family: "Product Sans Bold";
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 43px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
.center-table {
  display: table;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  text-align: justify !important;
}
.center-table p {
  text-align: justify !important;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.row{
  padding: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Any error messages in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue a few months ago. Depending upon your server, please try this replacement.

Take

and change to

Making that command change should prevent the video(s) from freezing. Please advise if it works.

Comment: What should I do? Change to what?

Comment: So sorry! My answer was truncated due to the addition of my coding example.  Take <div id="myvideo" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">  and change to  <div id="myvideo" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: auto;">

Comment: In theory, by replacing :"hidden" with "auto" on that one line, the videos should stop freezing; or better said, they should remain moving and aligned in time. Let me know if it works.

Comment: no it didnt help! JavaScript is crashing the browser. this is my website to check https://protected-dawn-92091.herokuapp.com/

Comment: There is an error in the DOMException process. This url will take you to the fix. I am 100% this will prevent the freezes you are seeing. Please advise and good luck! https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted#fix There is some JavaScript that needs a little tweaking and all should function, thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the DOMException process. This url will take you to the fix. I am 100% this will prevent the freezes you are seeing. Please advise and good luck!
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted#fix
There is some JavaScript that needs a little tweaking and all should function, thereafter.

Comment: There is an error in the DOMException process. This url will take you to the fix. I am 100% this will prevent the freezes you are seeing. Please advise and good luck! https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted#fix There is some JavaScript that needs a little tweaking and all should function, thereafter.